# How to rerun a migration

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I did create a migration

But in the Up() method i have call a resource to create a view like :

```
public override void Up()
    {
        Sql(Resources.GetString("sql1").AsSqlString());

        AddColumn("dbo.UserPreference", "ClientGraphCurrencyId", c => c.Int());
        CreateIndex("dbo.UserPreference", "ClientGraphCurrencyId");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.UserPreference", "ClientGraphCurrencyId", "dbo.Currency", "CurrencyId");
    }
```

After that i made change to "sql1" resource.

Question is how to re-run the migration so that update to sql1 applied to DB

I have try update-database but it say : No pending explicit migrations.

Comment: Do you have a Down method as well that reverts the change? if so you could update database to a previous migration make the changes you want to this one and reapply. If your down method does not revert (which it should) then add a new migration that reverts this one, and yet another that fixes this one.

Comment: In any case you may just add a new migration, that since there will be no changes picked up by ef, will have an empty up and down method. You may change the up and down to whatever you like and then update the database

Comment: Thanks, my final solution is to create new migration and add some code changes in Up() method as @GiannisParaskevopoulos comments